# Extract data really slow with a 30MB random data file

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file with about 215,000 lines. line by line and its random data and on the last line I have this "strA123456strB"

to process this its taking about 2 seconds on my computer but I am trying to reduce the processing time to just milliseconds.. any suggestions ?

I'm calling it like this

```
GetStringBetween(RichTextBox.Text, "strA", "strB")
```

this is the vb.net source

```
Function GetStringBetween(ByVal allData As String, ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String) As String
    Dim foundstr As String = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = allData.ToUpper().IndexOf(str1.ToUpper())
    Dim j As Integer
    If i > -1 Then
        allData = allData.Substring(i + str1.Length)
        j = allData.ToUpper().IndexOf(str2.ToUpper())
        If j > -1 Then
            foundstr = allData.Substring(0, j)
        End If
    End If
    Return foundstr
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried using Regex?

Comment: not really, how can I do that?

Comment: 1 minor thing, you're calling .ToUpper() twice on allData.   You could call it once at the beginning to save a little bit of time.  allData = allData.ToUpper()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an simple example for between search using Regex:

```
Dim allData = "nonmatch2_strA_match_strB_nonmatch2"
Dim r = Regex.Match(allData, "strA(.*)strB")
```

To ignore case, use RegexOptions:

```
Dim r = Regex.Match(allData, "strA(.*)strB", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

After the `r =` line finished execution, you can get the value it found like this:

```
r.Groups(1).Value
```