# How to get values between two inputed data

Tags: vb.net

I have textbox1 and textbox2 which will be the two inputed data, and I want to get the values between them. And the challenge is the ASCW character I and O is not included.

Im using this basis code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim tb1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim tb2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim cb As String = ""

    If tb1.Substring(tb1.Length - 1) <> tb2.Substring(tb2.Length - 1) Then

        While (tb1 <> tb2)
            Dim temp As String = tb1.Substring(0, tb1.Length - 1)
            Dim temp1 As Char = tb1(tb1.Length - 1)


           If AscW(UCase(temp1)) >= 48 And AscW(UCase(temp1)) < 90 Then

                temp1 = ChrW(AscW(UCase(temp1)) + 1)
            ElseIf AscW(UCase(temp1)) >= 90 Then
                temp1 = ChrW(AscW(UCase(temp1)) - 42)
            End If
            tb1 = temp & temp1
            If tb1 <> tb2 Then
                cb += tb1 & " "
            End If
        End While
        MessageBox.Show(cb)

    Else
        'Do here

        MessageBox.Show("none")
    End If

End Sub
```

Basic arrangement: A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AJ AK AL AM AN AP AQ AR AS AT AU AV AW AX AY AZ B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA...... ETC.

The ASCW character I and O is not included.

Example Scenario:
textbox1 = SF446DNLS
textbox2 = SF446DNNZ

Output:

> SF446DNLT SF446DNLU SF446DNLV SF446DNLW SF446DNLX SF446DNLY SF446DNLZ SF446DNM0 SF446DNM1 SF446DNM2 SF446DNM3 SF446DNM4 SF446DNM5 SF446DNM6 SF446DNM7 SF446DNM8 SF446DNM9 SF446DNMA SF446DNMB SF446DNMC SF446DNMD SF446DNME SF446DNMF SF446DNMG SF446DNMH SF446DNMJ SF446DNMK SF446DNML SF446DNMM SF446DNMN SF446DNMP SF446DNMQ SF446DNMR SF446DNMS SF446DNMT SF446DNMU SF446DNMV SF446DNMW SF446DNMX SF446DNMY SF446DNMZ SF446DNN0 SF446DNN1 SF446DNN2 SF446DNN3 SF446DNN4 SF446DNN5 SF446DNN6 SF446DNN7 SF446DNN8 SF446DNN9 SF446DNNA SF446DNNB SF446DNNC SF446DNND SF446DNNE SF446DNNF SF446DNNG SF446DNNH SF446DNNJ SF446DNNK SF446DNNL SF446DNNM SF446DNNN SF446DNNP SF446DNNQ SF446DNNR SF446DNNS SF446DNNT SF446DNNU SF446DNNV SF446DNNW SF446DNNX SF446DNNY  SF446DNNZ

Answer (score 0):

Check my other answer on [Extract data really slow with a 30MB random data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414837/extract-data-really-slow-with-a-30mb-random-data-file/24414941#24414941) for searching between two strings using Regex:

If you need to exclude I and O, use `^` (based on code in the above answer):

```
Dim allData = "nonmatch2_strA_match_strB_nonmatch2"
Dim r = Regex.Match(allData, "strA([^IO]*)strB")
```

You can further fine tune the expression to accept only numbers + characters, but without I and O using

- [Character Class Subtraction @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction)